# What is difference between new fnname and new fnname()?

Tags: javascript

I have created a class named `Class1` in Javascript.

```
function Class1(){}
```

Now, I can create object of `Class1` using the `new` operator. For example:

```
var obj1 = new Class1();
```

And I also recently found that you can use:

```
var obj1 = new Class1;
```

Are they the same or is there any difference in using them?

Comment: what's the difference between example line 2 and 3?

Comment: @Sebas: No; there is no difference.

Comment: @Sebas What does *syntax* have to do with OOP?

Comment: yes you're right, maybe I should refer to standards? What I mean is that this is definitely not what the common agreements tend to do. In fact I think Javascript is the only language allowing it. nb: the fiddle of my first comment should have been http://jsfiddle.net/Zg27x/

Comment: @Sebas: I've seen `new Class1` used in lots of places, I'd say it *is* "common".

Comment: @RocketHazmat, thanks for the info. Is there any other oop language permitting this?

Comment: @Sebas: [PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#example-171) :)  I don't know about any others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As specified in [ECMAScript 5](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf), i.e. the Javascript specification:

> #### 11.2.2 The new Operator
>
> The production `new NewExpression` is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let ref be the result of evaluating NewExpression.
> 2. Let constructor be GetValue(ref).
> 3. If Type(constructor) is not Object, throw a TypeError exception.
> 4. If constructor does not implement the [[Construct]] internal method, throw a TypeError exception.
> 5. Return the result of calling the [[Construct]] internal method on constructor, providing no arguments (that  is, an empty list of arguments).
>
> The production `new MemberExpression Arguments` is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let ref be the result of evaluating MemberExpression.
> 2. Let constructor be GetValue(ref).
> 3. Let argList be the result of evaluating Arguments, producing an internal list of argument values (11.2.4).
> 4. If Type(constructor) is not Object, throw a TypeError exception.
> 5. If constructor does not implement the [[Construct]] internal method, throw a TypeError exception.
> 6. Return the result of calling the [[Construct]] internal method on constructor, providing the list argList as the  argument values.

So, `new Foo` will call `Foo` with an empty list of arguments, just as `new Foo()` does.

There is no difference between the two syntaxes.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference. The `()` are inferred by the interpreter if you don't add them. It's even a widely used optimization trick.

If your constructor does not take any parameters you can simply do:

```
new MyClass1
```

And the parentheses will be added automatically, just like semi-colon insertion. Beware though, it's only the `new` keyword that forces this behaviour.

Instantiation is the only scenario where you are allowed to skip the parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

It's just shorthand syntax.  If you're not passing any parameters to the constructor, you can leave off the parenthesis.

```
var obj1 = new Class1;
```

is exactly the same as

```
var obj1 = new Class1();
```